# golang closure in closure

Tags: go, closures

a closure problem
example looks like this:

```golang
uids := []int{1, 2, 3}
wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
for _, uid := range uids {
   wg.Add(1)
   go func() {
      func(id int) {
         defer wg.Done()
         fmt.Println(id)
      }(uid)
   }()
}
wg.Wait()
```

why this result is

```
3 3 3
```

what's the difference between

```golang
uids := []int{1, 2, 3}
wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
for _, uid := range uids {
   wg.Add(1)
   go func(id int) {
         defer wg.Done()
         fmt.Println(id)
   }(uid)
}
wg.Wait()
```

which result is

```
3 1 2
```

Comment: The first version has data race, no reason to reason about it. The launched goroutines read the `uid` loop variable while the main goroutine modifies it.

Comment: See the FAQ: https://go.dev/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines